# Install tensorflow-gpu on windows 10

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow

I found all information about python3 but cannot find anything about python2.

```
> pip install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu
    Collecting tensorflow-gpu
    Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-gpu (from versions: )
    No matching distribution found for tensorflow-gpu
```

I followed https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows#CommonInstallationProblems and http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-microsoft-windows/ to install CUDA and I get:

```
> nvcc -V
    nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
    Copyright (c) 2005-2017 NVIDIA Corporation
    Built on Fri_Nov__3_21:08:12_Central_Daylight_Time_2017
    Cuda compilation tools, release 9.1, V9.1.85
```

So I think I am good on this side. 
I just need the `pip` command to install `tensorflow-gpu`.

I found a link to a version of `tensorflow-gpu` which should work, copied the link and tried but I get that:

```
> pip install --upgrade https://pypi.python.org/packages/23/ad/63ae65999fd42a3e8d0044245e52513b31764167797651bef3ceb5202001/tensorflow_gpu-1.7.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl#md5=7d780aa2c9f73c1ea9d3b87422aca096
    tensorflow_gpu-1.7.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

**EDIT:**

So I uninstall python2 and reinstall python3 but it still does not work:

```
> pip --version
    pip 9.0.3 from c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages (python 3.6)
> pip install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu
    Collecting tensorflow-gpu
    Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-gpu (from versions: )
    No matching distribution found for tensorflow-gpu
```

**EDIT:**

I wrote an article about it: https://leobenkel.com/2018/04/tensorflow-gpu-windows10-tutorial/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install Tensorflow on Python 2.7 on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45316569/how-to-install-tensorflow-on-python-2-7-on-windows)

Comment: I updated my questions, I gave up on using python2

Comment: You have reinstalled **32** bit of python . Install **64 bit** not 32 bit. Check my other [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38896424/tensorflow-not-found-in-pip/47582761#47582761)

Comment: I found this page saying that `tensorflow-gpu` only works with python3.5 , is that true ? https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8251

Comment: [official site](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows#requirements_to_run_tensorflow_with_gpu_support)

Comment: Rather than using `pip install` try to install with conda distribution. It was mention in the official web site in tensorflow. For conda installation follow this [link](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/tensorflow-gpu)

Answer (score 0):

For now Tensorflow is only supported on **64 bits installations** of Python versions 3.5 and 3.6

> If one of the following versions of Python is not installed on your
>   machine, install it now:
>
> ```
> Python 3.5.x 64-bit from python.org
> Python 3.6.x 64-bit from python.org
> ```

Check TensorFlow website for more [details](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows)

Comment: I have constraint about using python2. It is not possible ?

Comment: Its not released. Perhaps there is no workaround than using 64 bit of Python now.

Comment: ok, I am gonna try to use python3 then, but it is not very convenient. Thanks for the help

Comment: I removed python2 and installed python3 instead but it still does not work. I updated my question.

Comment: @Wonay you have installed 32 bit of python .tensorflow only works on 64 bit. Install 64 bit python

Answer (score 0):

while i was trying to install the gpu based tensorflow the same problem was found,and that was the versions not satisfy. and solution to the problem i found after searching was if you have currently installing the latest version of python suppose at first i had install python3.7.x and when i was try to install the gpu version tensorflow the problem arose. reason was the for new version of python the tensorflow-gpu was not release yet . so ,you have to install the later version say  python3.6 version type to make it works. 
good luck!!