# How to install tensorflow for python 2.7?

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow

I installed python 2.7 in windows 10 environment using conda. According to documentation of tensorflow, it only supports version 3 and above. Is there any way to install tensorflow while keeping python version 2.7?

Comment: I improved my question for better understanding of the community. If you think it is easy to understand, then upvote please.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install Tensorflow on Python 2.7 on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45316569/how-to-install-tensorflow-on-python-2-7-on-windows)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"TensorFlow supports Python 3.5.x and 3.6.x on Windows."

Hence you can not use tensorflow with Python 2.7 on Windows

- if your are forced to used Python 2.7 you set up a virtual machine using virtual     box with linux as guest.
- if you have the option to use python 3.x (e.g. python 3.6) you can install anaconda with python 3.6. https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-5.1.0-Windows-x86_64.exe
- if you have anaconda with python 2.7 you can define a environment.yml and then create conda env 
  https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-from-an-environment-yml-file 
  https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#create-env-file-manually

   It might be the case that with Python 2.7 you can't create a Python 3.x enviroment. 
   Try it out.

Once you have a Anaconda with Python 3.6 you can simply

`conda install tensorflow`