# pip automatically downloading requirements

Tags: python, pip

I use pip2 to install `tensorflow-gpu(1.8.0)`, and the `tensorflow-gpu` requires the `numpy>=1.13.0`, so pip2 automatically download the newest version of numpy(which is 1.19.1), but the newest numpy does not support python2.7 so that I fail to install tensorflow-gpu. I want to know if I can cancel the automatically download and install the numpy by myself? Or is there other method to install tensorflow1.8.0 in python2.7? The log outputted by pip2 is as follow:

[log to install tensorflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDG9m.png)

Comment: the image seems unavailable, the log is as follow:

Comment: Why use pip2 when you can use the `pip` command to install tensorflow?

Comment: Did you try to manually pip install numpy==1.13.0 ?  That should satisfy the requiremen.

Comment: I want to run codes that was implemented by python 2.7 , so I have no choice

Comment: Here your answer... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50044649/how-to-install-tensorflow-for-python-2-7#

Comment: Yes, I try, but when I install tensorflow, pip2 try to download the newest version of numpy

Comment: Thank you, I will try it first.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify multiple packages with version numbers:

```
pip2 install tensorflow-gpu==1.8.0 numpy==1.13.3
```

Note that `tensorflow-gpu 1.8.0` has requirement `numpy>=1.13.3`.