# Tensorflow on mac cpu first run gives an error

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've installed cpu version following [page](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip?lang=python2) indications. And it gives me the following error when trying to run tensorflow:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/francisco/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "/Users/francisco/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/Users/francisco/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/francisco/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/Users/francisco/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/Users/francisco/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/francisco/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so, 6): Symbol not found: _clock_gettime
  Referenced from: /Users/francisco/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/../libtensorflow_framework.so (which was built for Mac OS X 10.12)
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
 in /Users/francisco/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/../libtensorflow_framework.so
```

I tried to install from the wheel url

`curl -O https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.12.0-py2-none-any.whl`

But it continues throwing the same error

Answer (score 0):

Tensor flow is only supported by Python 3.5 and Python 3.6.

I highly recommending downloading a pre-compiled version from Anaconda [here](https://www.anaconda.com/download/).

Comment: Nope. Installation page clearly indicates that there is a version for python 2.7 and offers a radio button to select instructions for installation.

Comment: My apologies - you are right. There's some conflicting messages about what is and isn't supported. Not to patronize, but did you only do the wheel install, or did you do `pip install --upgrade tensorflow` and then verify the installation, too?

Comment: It's ok. Yes, I've done `pip install --upgrade tensorflow` and after that `python -c "import tensorflow as tf; tf.enable_eager_execution(); print(tf.reduce_sum(tf.random_normal([1000, 1000])))"`

Comment: That's ok. Any way that I try to import Tensorflow, including this, outputs the same error.

Comment: Please take a look at this thread. I've personally gone through the hassle that you are going through while attempting to install tensorflow on python 2.7.

Comment: I'm sorry Daniel but I don't find what thread you're talking about. Did you intended to post a link?

Comment: @panchtox My sincere apologies. Here you go: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45316569/how-to-install-tensorflow-on-python-2-7-on-windows

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186373/discussion-between-panchtox-and-daniel-scott).