# How to install tensorflow for python 2?

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow

I would like to use tensorflow with ROS and ROS 1 does only support python 2.7 at the moment.
Is there a way to install tensorflow 1 or 2 for python 2.7?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to this older post: [How to install Tensorflow on Python 2.7 on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45316569/how-to-install-tensorflow-on-python-2-7-on-windows)
Tensorflow does not support python2.7 anymore.

This is the system requirement for Tensorflow available: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip?hl=en :

- System requirements
- Python **3.5–3.8**
- Python 3.8 support requires TensorFlow 2.2 or later.
- pip 19.0 or later (requires manylinux2010 support)
- Ubuntu 16.04 or later (64-bit)
- macOS 10.12.6 (Sierra) or later (64-bit) (no GPU support)
- Windows 7 or later (64-bit)
- Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019
- Raspbian 9.0 or later
- GPU support requires a CUDA®-enabled card (Ubuntu and Windows)

Here you have the reference to the C++ reference: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/cc

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way of using tensorflow is to download anaconda and then download the packages of anaconda!

Comment: But I can't run the python script as `boost::python::object` in a c++ file. There ros always takes its python version which is python 2.7.
So I need to install tensorflow there.