# Error in importing Sequential from Keras.Models

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, keras, python-2.x

I have installed Keras using `pip install keras` and tensorflow version 1.9.0 via `python -m pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.9.0-py2-none-any.whl`. I followed the directions at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38896424/tensorflow-not-found-using-pip) and chose a version that seemed to be able to install on my computer. I am not sure if it is because the version is too old. I am using Python 2 on a Windows computer. I am running the following import statements and get the following error message.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Downloads\keras_code.py", line 2, in <module>
    from keras.models import Sequential
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import tf2
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    import _pywrap_tensorflow_internal
ImportError: No module named _pywrap_tensorflow_internal


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Getting a new computer will not be possible instantaneously, is there a way to get keras/tensorflow to work on an older computer?

Comment: on window python 2.7 not support TensorFlow
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45316569/how-to-install-tensorflow-on-python-2-7-on-windows

Answer (score 0):

@Jellyfish, you are using very old Tensorflow version. Install the latest Tensorflow version, 2.6.0. Latest Tensorflow version installs Keras library as well.

Use imports as below.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
```

Comment: Some explanation is required here as the answer may not be clear.

Comment: The op is for python 2, so no, this is not a working answer.