# install tensorflow on python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, anaconda

I want to install tensorflow on python 2.7
I built environment for python 2.7 on conda(windows 10).
but when I try to install tensorflow by "conda install tensorflow", I got a error massage like under.

```
===========================================================================
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: /
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.-
failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found
to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:

Specifications:

  - tensorflow -> python[version='3.5.*|3.6.*|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0|3.7.*|3.8.*|3.9.*']

Your python: python=2.7

If python is on the left-most side of the chain, that's the version you've asked for.
When python appears to the right, that indicates that the thing on the left is somehow
not available for the python version you are constrained to. Note that conda will not
change your python version to a different minor version unless you explicitly specify
that.
===========================================================
```

when I use pip with [pip install tensorflow], I got massage

```
========================
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow
========================
```

I already know current tensorflow doesn't support python 2.7, but I still need tensorflow working at python 2.7

what should I do for install tensorflow for python 2.7 at conda environment?
It doesn't matter if tensorflow version is 1.0.0 or higher.

Comment: Even if you are able to install it, there is a great chance that tensorflow will not work. These requirements are usually selected such that any lower versions do not have necessary tools for the framework to function properly. You may need to find a much older version of tensorflow and install it manually.

Comment: You will need to find some older version of TensorFlow if you want to run it on Python 2. But do you really want to? Unless you really really know what you are doing, you should almost certainly be using the currently supported version of the language, which is Python 3.

Comment: I am a student, and I want to reproduce and study the code written on the paper. However, the code is composed of TensorFlow in Python 2.7, so I want to build this environment.

Comment: What is you OS? On my linux machine I can simply do `conda create -n TFTest -c conda-forge tensorflow python=2.7`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install Tensorflow on Python 2.7 on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45316569/how-to-install-tensorflow-on-python-2-7-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

Latest versions of Tensorflow does not support Python2.7

**System Requirements**

1. Python 3.6–3.9
   Python 3.9 support requires TensorFlow 2.5 or later.
   Python 3.8 support requires TensorFlow 2.2 or later.
2. pip 19.0 or later (requires manylinux2010 support)
3. Ubuntu 16.04 or later (64-bit)
4. macOS 10.12.6 (Sierra) or later (64-bit) (no GPU support)
5. macOS requires pip 20.3 or later
6. Windows 7 or later (64-bit)
7. Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015, 2017
   and 2019
8. GPU support requires a CUDA®-enabled card (Ubuntu and Windows)

Answer (score 0):

`conda install tensorflow` will still try to fetch the latest stable version of Tensorflow, which again is not compatible with Python 2.7.

But wait, you can ask `conda` and `pip` to install **a specific version** of a package. Using Tensorflow 2.1 (the last supported version for Python 2.7), for example:

- `conda install tensorflow=2.1`
- `pip install -Iv tensorflow==2.1` (note the additional equal sign there)

And yes, you can also put that (`tensorflow==2.1`) into your `requirements.txt` file too.